# How to use a wetmap to distribute particles (how to distribute plants where moisture collects)

Tags: particles, vertex-colors, vertex-weights, vertex-paint

This is a follow-up to this question - [Geometry nodes: How to distribute points on valleys only?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239367/geometry-nodes-how-to-distribute-points-on-valleys-only)

One of the approaches considered was using particles to simulate rain, then using the wet map from dynamic paint to calculate where water flows and accumulates in a landscape. The animation below shows the surface with wet and dry areas.

[image]

I'd like to use the wet maps to distribute particles or apply modifiers that rely on vertex weights. Additionally, I'd like to be able to do this as part of an animation.

Is there a way to move the wet map to a vertex map as part of an animation? A preferred solution would not involve python.

The file used to generate this image is here - [image]

Comment: As suggested in a comment of this question [How to convert a wet or paint map to a weight map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239891/how-to-convert-a-wet-or-paint-map-to-a-weight-map) you can bake the DP as an image sequence and use these images to control the particle distribution =>https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUIsp.jpg It requires a bake step and a UV map. Your mountain mesh is quite dense but it works. -- Maybe also helpful [Is it possible to get a weight paint value for a vertex group inside of a material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/224166/107598)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Particle Distribution

For the particle distribution, you can bake the *Dynamic Paint* (the wetmap to be precise) to an image sequence. The landscape object must be UV unwrapped for this to work.

**Baking Step**

- create the UV map for the landscape object. It will take a minute or two because your mountain landscape has many vertices.
- in the *Dynamic Paint* settings of the canvas (landscape object) choose *Format:* `Image Sequence` and a higher *Resolution*, for example, `512`.
- expand the *Output* section, enter a folder name for *Cache Path*. This is where the baked images will be saved. The press the <kbd>Bake Image Sequence</kbd> button.

Done this, you can deactivate the *Dynamic Paint* physics on the canvas and the brush with *monitor* and *camera* icons on the *Dynamic Paint* section in the *Physics* tab or alternatively, on the modifier itself.

**Using the Baked Image Sequence**

Use the baked image sequence for the shader to visualize it.

- choose *Open* on the *Image Texture* node and select all images with <kbd>A</kbd>. Make sure they are ordered by the file name to have them in the correct order.
- enable `[X]` *Auto Refresh* for the *Image Texture* node
- set the *Number of Frames*

[image: shader setup w/ image seq]

Then create a *Particle System* for the landscape object.

- type is *Hair*, activate the `[X]` *Advanced* option
- use the cone (tree) object as rendered object (*Render > Re[]nder As* = `Object` and *.. > Object > Instance Object* = the cone). Increase the *.. > Scale* to a higher values like `0.2`.
- activate the `[X]` Rotation (advanced option), and set *Orientation Axis* to `Object Y` to have the trees all vertically aligned.
- in the *Textures* section of the *Particle System* create a new texture in the first slot with the <kbd>New</kbd> button below.

Switch to the *Textures* tab.

- select the image sequence that you have created for the shader
- tick `[X]` Auto Refresh and check if the *Number of Frames* value is correct
- in the *Influence* section, tick [X] *Density*. And [X] *Hair Length* if you want to have the size affected.
- set *Mapping* to `UV` and select the correct UV map if you have more than one

[image: particle settings]
(the particle system has a few old bugs. Sometimes it doesn't update and you have to do a change and revert the change immediately. Here for example are tiny trees... no idea why. *Hair Length* is not checked).

## Geometry Nodes - Point Distribution

This is rather easy to do in Blender 2.93.5 because you can access the vertex color that is created by the Dynamic Paint physics directly in the geometry node:

[image: geometry node setup]

The drawback here is that it is very slow when you replay the animation.

**Related question**

[Is it possible to get a weight paint value for a vertex group inside of a material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/224166/107598)

Comment: the 2nd part using Geometry Nodes was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!